# Knockout Checked Binding Doesnt Work With Radio Button

Tags: knockout.js

The knockout checked binding is not working, has followed below example given by knockout.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html

The code can be seen at following.

http://jsfiddle.net/c2TSm/

```
var viewModel = {
    wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
    spamFlavor: ko.observable("almond") // Initially selects only the Almond radio button
};

// ... then later ...
viewModel.spamFlavor("msg"); // Now only Monosodium Glutamate is checked
```

The value of Monosodium Glutamate should be selected by default. once page load first time.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to call `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`